# For versions of solr9 or later, the admin UI cannot be displayed

Tags: user-interface, solr, admin

jdk:openjdk11
The previous version of Solr was 8.11.3, which showed the operation and the AdminUI interface. Now due to security issues, you need to upgrade to 9.2, after the deployment is running, the running status is normal, but the admin UI management interface cannot be opened
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQhys.png)

jdk:openjdk11
The previous version of Solr was 8.11.3, which showed the operation and the AdminUI interface. Now due to security issues, you need to upgrade to 9.2, after the deployment is running, the running status is normal, but the admin UI management interface cannot be opened

Comment: Please clarify your question. You say "the running status is normal, but the admin UI management interface cannot be opened". What error message do you see when attempting to open the Admin UI?